# Getting Error: "Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void(^)"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the code below to verify that my Shopify check out was successful... However the line:

```
 [self.client getCompletionStatusOfCheckout:self.checkout
 completion:^(BUYCheckout *checkout, BUYStatus status, NSError *error)
 {
```

is throwing me the strangest error:

> "Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void(^)(BUYCheckout
>   *___Strong, BUYStatus, NSError *___Strong' to parameter type 'BUYDataCheckoutStatusBlock''

How can I fix this? And what does it mean? Let me know if you need more code/details. Cheers.

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) BUYClient *client;
```

**.m**

```
-(void)verifyCheckout{

    __block BUYStatus buyStatus = BUYStatusUnknown;
    __block BUYCheckout *completedCheckout = self.checkout;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    do {

        [self.client getCompletionStatusOfCheckout:self.checkout completion:^(BUYCheckout *checkout, BUYStatus status, NSError *error) {
            completedCheckout = checkout;
            buyStatus = status;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        if (buyStatus == BUYStatusProcessing) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
        } else {

        }

    } while (completedCheckout.token && buyStatus != BUYStatusFailed && buyStatus != BUYStatusComplete);

}
```

Comment: Update your question with the declaration for `BUYDataCheckoutStatusBlock` and the `getCompletionStatus:` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shopify documentation says that the completion block takes in only two parameters:

```
typedef void (^BUYDataCheckoutStatusBlock)(BUYStatus status, NSError *error);
```

So the line

```
 [self.client getCompletionStatusOfCheckout:self.checkout
 completion:^(BUYCheckout *checkout, BUYStatus status, NSError *error)
 {
```

Should instead be

```
[self.client getCompletionStatusOfCheckout:self.checkout
 completion:^(BUYStatus status, NSError *error)
 {
```